# Laravel: Many to Many, how to insert data?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I've got for the first time in L4 the need to establish a many-to-many relationship. For what I understood, so far, I need three tables... I have the following:

```
users
- id
- username
- ...

platforms
- id
- title
- ...

users_platforms
- platform_id
- user_id
```

How can I now insert data into the users_platforms table? I have the User model and the Platform model. How should both these be related... and how the actual content is saved to the related table?

On `hasMany` relationships I would create a new user and then save it like `$user->something()->save($something)` but I naturally can't do something like that in here.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a User model with your relation:

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    public function platforms()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Platform', 'users_platforms');
    }

}
```

You just have to `attach` it:

```
$platform = new Platform;
$platform->name = 'OSX';
$platform->save();

$user = User::find(1);

$user->platforms()->attach($platform->id);
```

Comment: That sounds simple! All I need to do is add a platforms() function with manyToMany into the User model? No need to make any other relationships?